# How to get latest code from react-native using react-native-git-upgrade?

Tags: git, react-native, react-native-git-upgrade

Im using `react-native-git-upgrade` to keep the system updated, however there are some imp updated I need that are not part of any tag yet and are only in commits.

So how to get that?

Usually the following works with releases:

```
react-native-git-upgrade X.Y.Z
```

But how to get latest commits from master branch? I tried the following:

```
react-native-git-upgrade master
```

this didnt work

Comment: Any error message?